# Proguard configuration for appcompat v7 not working

Tags: android, proguard, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I'm using proguard  for my application. added below code in proguard-project.txt

```
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
```

But after installing signed apk app gets crashed. getting null pointer exception at

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

is there any missing line?

Comment: Use the default proguard that comes with the SDK!

Answer (score 0):

Check if your activities are getting renamed (by extracting APK). If so, try adding them into one package and then add

```
- keep public class your.package.with.activites.* { *; }
```

to proguard-project.txt